# Meaning of "Blood, Fish and Bone"

Tags: meaning

For this text:

> The weeds on the compost heap, I began feeding the shrubs with Blood, Fish and Bone.----

I am wondering whether the "Blood, Fish and Bone" above indicates "the weeds" and "the compost heap" or not, or indicates something else?

The context is :

> And she'd reply, "I prefer to be called by my maiden name, from now on."
>
> The weeds on the compost heap, I began feeding the shrubs with Blood, Fish and Bone. Three miles away Patrick Beeman would be working down a list of bullet points with Lorna: General Procedure, Custody, Money, House, Pensions, Miscellaneous, Standard Fees.

---

Excerpted from David Mitchell's novel "The Massive Rat":

http://www.theguardian.com/books/2009/aug/01/david-mitchell-short-story-rat

---

[Edit, following comments received:
I now think the narrator used the *Blood, Fish and Bone* to feed the shrubs.
It seems I have to learn something about the gardening...]

Comment: "Blood, Fish and Bone" seems to be a U.K. brand of fertilizer (Google it).

Comment: @PeterShor: That would make a great name for a law firm, too. :^)

Comment: @PeterShor I wouldn't call it a "brand". It's a common fertiliser mix that may be sold by various manufacturers under various *brand names*.

Comment: @PeterShor thank you. there is a brand name called "Blood, Fish and Bone" indeed.so call it a brand name would be very good.----
>This contains 3 major nutrients for strong and healthy plant growth. The nitrogen encourages healthy and rich green foliage the phosphate promotes vigorous root growth and the potash encourages flower colour and improves ripening or fruits and vegetables.

Comment: @PeterShor thank you. there is a brand name called "Blood, Fish and Bone" indeed.so call it a brand name would be very good.---- >This contains 3 major nutrients for strong and healthy plant growth. The nitrogen encourages healthy and rich green foliage the phosphate promotes vigorous root growth and the potash encourages flower colour and improves ripening or fruits and vegetables.

Answer (score 2):

Blood Fish and Bone is a granulated fertiliser.  It can be mixed with the soil when planting, or sprinkled on the soil surface to feed existing plants.

Comment: thank you. there is a brand name called "Blood, Fish and Bone" indeed.so call it a brand name would be very good.---- >This contains 3 major nutrients for strong and healthy plant growth. The nitrogen encourages healthy and rich green foliage the phosphate promotes vigorous root growth and the potash encourages flower colour and improves ripening or fruits and vegetables.

Answer (score 1):

The first clause is an ellipsis; either *Having put* the weeds on the compost heap...' or 'The weeds *having been thrown* on the compost heap...'

And yes; blood, fishmeal and bone are very good organic fertilizer.

Comment: thank you. there is a brand name called "Blood, Fish and Bone" indeed.so call it a brand name would be very good.---- >This contains 3 major nutrients for strong and healthy plant growth. The nitrogen encourages healthy and rich green foliage the phosphate promotes vigorous root growth and the potash encourages flower colour and improves ripening or fruits and vegetables.